# Lambda function triggered continuously by ObjectRemoved event

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, triggers, aws-lambda

I created a Lambda function for deleting a given thumbnail and I set a trigger on the ObjectRemoved event in order to automatically delete a thumbnail image when the original file was deleted from a given aws-S3 bucket.

However, by analyzing the monthly bill I realized that for some reason that Lambda was called hundred millions of times and wouldn't stop to be triggered. I had to disable the trigger on the Lambda to disable it.

The problem is I have not created or deleted any file on that bucket, so I wonder how it's possible the lambda function continued to be triggered continuously.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit:

My AWS Lambda code

```js
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new aws.S3();
exports.handler = function (event, context) {
    console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

    // Get the object from the event and show its content type
    const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    const key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
    const path = key.split('/');
    const folder = path[0];
    const fileName = path[1];
    const deleteKey = folder + '/thumbnails/' + fileName;

    s3.deleteObject({ Bucket: bucket, Key: deleteKey }, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error deleting object ' + deleteKey + ' from bucket ' + bucket + '. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.');
            context.fail('Error getting file: ' + err)
        } else {
            context.succeed();
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Could you please share your code? Without seeing it it's very hard to analyze the problem.

Comment: What code do you need? I have only the code of the Lambda function, since it is only triggered by S3. I just realized that the Lambda function was also triggered after the same Lambda deleted the thumbnail. The strange thing is that if I delete the file with key 'pictures/<file_key>' the first time the Lambda correctly deletes 'pictures/thumbnails/<file_key>', the second time (my mistake) the Lambda is triggered to remove 'pictures/thumbnails/<file_key>' that, obviously, no longer exists,

Comment: but the next times, endlessly, the Lambda is triggered to remove 'pictures/thumbnails/thumbnails' which has no sense since the previous call did not delete any file. I wonder why the Lambda keeps being triggered if no file was deleted by the previous (wrong) call...

Comment: To see the code of your AWS Lambda would be nice.

Comment: `var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new aws.S3();

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    // Get the object from the event and show its content type
    const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    const key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
    const path = key.split('/');
    const folder = path[0];
    const fileName = path[1];
    const deleteKey = folder + '/thumbnails/' + fileName;
`

Comment: `s3.deleteObject({Bucket: bucket, Key: deleteKey}, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error deleting object " + deleteKey + " from bucket " + bucket +
                ". Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.");
            context.fail ("Error getting file: " + err)      
        } else {
            context.succeed();
        }
    });
};`

Comment: Why are you not putting this code into your question ._. ?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I tried fixing my bug by separating the thumbnail folder from the one containing the original files and set the ObjectRemoved event trigger only on the latter. Now the Lambda should only be triggered when I delete an original file and not a thumbnail. However, I noticed that the endless triggering continues since the Lambda is required to remove a file that no longer exists since it was deleted on a previous call...

Comment: Ok, now I deleted the trigger and created a new one but on ObjectRemoved:DELETE and the Lambda seems to be correctly invoked once as expected. I hope it's a viable solution and not just an hotfix.

Comment: @FabioD your code needs to be more defensive and avoid reacting to events triggered by its own action.  Deletion in S3 is idempotent -- you can *continually* *successfully* delete an object *that has already been deleted.* This is confusing until you realize that "delete" *does not mean* "find this object and remove it" -- it means "ensure that there is no such object." I had never considered whether a delete event would fire in such a case, but it would make sense.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot for the clarification. I understand the idempotency, and it makes sense, but I still don't understand why the Lambda kept being trigger if no file was actually deleted or marked to be deleted, since the key did not exist. I wonder what kept generating the event, and why restricting the event to DELETED solved the problem. I read about a similar problem but with a Lambda creating a new file each time a new file was created in a bucket in a recursive behavior, but it wasn't my case.

Comment: @FabioD note that your code *does* have a bug -- you are lacking a sanity check -- that causes it to potentially recurse.  Deleting `foo/bar.png` causes your code to try to delete `foo/thumbnails/bar.png` which then causes your code to try to delete `foo/thumbnails/thumbnails` in a potentially endless loop, because you assume `path.length` is always 2 and don't do the right thing when it isn't.  After `const fileName = path[1];` add this test: `if(fileName === 'thumbnails') { return context.fail("d'oh."); }`

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you're right, I know the function has bugs, also due to the S3 bucket structure. That's why I changed the bucket structure by separating the original and the thumbnail folders and put the trigger only on the first one. This fixed a few bugs but not the fact the Lambda kept trying to delete an already deleted file in the original folder because S3 kept triggering it on the same file successfully deleted in the first invocation. Now, since the Lambda deleted a file on the other folder not included in the trigger I wonder why S3 kept triggering on the original file deletion.

Comment: @FabioD that is confusing.  If your function returns an error, it will be retried, but only twice, so that seems unrelated... however, if that is combined with incorrect behavior, it could still go exponential rather quickly. The S3 events contain `responseElements['x-amz-request-id']` which matches the `Request ID` field in the bucket logs, so if this value differs across events then S3 is not actually replaying a single delete action. Also `s3.object.sequencer` is a hex counter that indicates the order in which event-creating operations for a given object occurred; console.log both of these.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot that's the point. I don't think the S3 was replaying the same delete action, but rather triggered a new deletion request after each Lambda execution. According to what you said before S3 is idempotent, hence if the Lambda tries to remove a not existing file it should not return an error. What I don't really understand is why with ObjectRemoved triggered the Lambda of a not existing file deletion while ObjectRemoved:DELETE triggered the Lambda only once as desired.

Comment: OK, I performed other tests with the old code and novel bucket structure, hence the Lambda tries to delete not existing files after I manually delete a file on the original folder. The trigger is set on the original file folder only. As expected, the Lambda does not return any error, but the S3 keeps triggering it on a not existing file. At this point, I think that the S3 triggers the deletion event just because the deletion did not fail disregarding whether the file actually exists or not...